# NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingleton

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-jmx

I was recently running into an issue using Spring JMX. The only thing I want to reach is to export a simple Spring Bean for monitoring with JConsole. My goal is to integrate Spring JMX into an existing Spring web application running on an embedded Jetty server. But every time I start the application having JMX configured im running into the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter] for bean with name 'exporter' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/max.mustermann/workspace_intranetportal/my_webapp/target/classes/META-INF/appContext.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingleton
```

Google couldn't help me so far.

My Spring Bean looks like this:

```
public class JmxTestBean implements IJmxTestBean {

private String  name;
private int     age;
private boolean isTest;

@Override
public int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

@Override
public long myOperation() {
    return 10L;
}

@Override
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

@Override
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And these are the lines I added to Spring's appContext.xml:

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
            <entry key="test:name=testBean" value-ref="testBean" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="testBean" class="com.big.intranet.test.JmxTestBean">
    <property name="name" value="TEST" />
    <property name="age" value="100" />
</bean>
```

Deleting the lines I just showed you, the application is running fine. Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Judging from the stack trace you are mixing jars from different versions of spring.. Don't mix jars of different versions of a framework..

Comment: Tanks M. Deinum! I actually mixed different versions of Spring AOP and Spring Beans. Now the exception is gone and Jetty starts as expected, But still my bean doesn't show up in JConsole...

Comment: Ok t's solved now. The beans-tag attribute 'default-lazy-init' has been set to 'true', but this behavior does not work for Spring MBeans. Therefore the exporter bean requires the 'lazy-init' attribute been set to 'false'. Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already pointed out in my comment, there're two essential requirements that should be followed when working with Spring JMX:

1. As [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) explained, always make sure that your Spring dependencies share the same version and that - if possible - always the latest version is used.
2. Be careful that the bean tag's *lazy_init* attribute is at least set to **false** (which should be the default behavior if I remember correctly).

Following these rules, everything should work well. Thank you all for participating!

Answer (score 3):

I have update from spring 4.0.0.RELEASE to 4.1.5.RELEASE, this solved my problem.

Comment: Did you upgrade Spring core ?

Comment: I have added to the all spring jars that were there in my pom file. If you are not using maven, it will bit difficult to manage the dependencies. I suggest to use maven.

Comment: Makes sense, looks like SmartInitializingSingleton was only introduced in version 4.1.0 of the spring-beans jar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I changed the validator dependency from springfox-bean-validators:2.6.1 to hibernate-validator:5.3.4.Final. Then it worked.